# How to Bold (Span) the searched text in string dynamically?

Tags: android, string, spannable, spannablestringbuilder

I have a string, in which i have to find a word being searched from end user and make it bold to highlight.

Example:

String : Address must have a format. Address can be of multiple line.

Required Text: **Address** must have a format. **Address** can be of multiple line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through different Approaches. I have written the following method which will span the searched Text in string.

If you want to span the same text multiple time they can use this method as well.

```
public CharSequence highlightTextString(String completeText, String searchText) {
    String temp = completeText.toLowerCase();
    SpannableStringBuilder highlightText = new SpannableStringBuilder(completeText);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchText.toLowerCase());
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        StyleSpan styleSpan = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
        highlightText.setSpan(styleSpan, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
    }
    return highlightText;
}
```